# Tests fail only on github actions with rails, elasticsearch and searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, github-actions, searchkick

`Ruby 3.0.3` `Rails 7.0.0.alpha2` `elasticsearch 7.17.1` `searchkick 5.0.3`

My tests are all passing on `local` but not on GitHub action and I don't know why...
Do you know how to show the details of the error 500?
This is a Capybara test

[This is the config that I added](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeOcculy/0942c4acb8ebc3b52545a0607440ea31)

The results

```rb
Run echo $ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL
http://localhost:49154
health
green
create index
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    99  100    66  100    33    985    492 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1477
{"acknowledged":true,"shards_acknowledged":true,"index":"iot_log"}read_only_allow_delete
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    67  100    21  100    46   3000   6571 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9571
{"acknowledged":true}watermarks
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   654  100   418  100   236  12294   6941 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 19818
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "persistent" : { },
  "transient" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "disk" : {
            "watermark" : {
              "low" : "50gb",
              "flood_stage" : "10gb",
              "high" : "20gb"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "info" : {
        "update" : {
          "interval" : "1m"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```rb
Run bundle exec rails test
  bundle exec rails test
  bundle exec rails test:controllers
  # bundle exec rails test test/controllers/companies_controller_test.rb:105
  bundle exec rails test:system
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    RAILS_ENV: test
    NODE_ENV: test
    ES_HOME: /home/runner/elasticsearch/7.17.1
    DB_PASSWORD: postgres
    DB_PORT: 5432
    REDIS_PORT: 49153
    ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL: http://localhost:49154
Running 33 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 9006

# Running:

F

Failure:
TasksControllerTest#test_should_destroy_task_&_related_permission(s)_where_user_!=_assignee [/home/runner/work/hubflo/hubflo/test/controllers/tasks_controller_test.rb:134]:
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>

rails test test/controllers/tasks_controller_test.rb:128
```

## Edit with answers

So I used the `rescue_from` option from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71734263/2679301)
The error was

```rb
#<Searchkick::ImportError: {"type"=>"index_not_found_exception", "reason"=>"no such index [companies_test]", "resource.type"=>"index_expression", "resource.id"=>"companies_test", "index_uuid"=>"_na_", "index"=>"companies_test"} on item with id '650928[31](https://github.com/Hubflo-sas/hubflo/runs/5795678731?check_suite_focus=true#step:16:31)2'>
F

Failure:
CompaniesControllerTest#test_should_destroy_company [/home/runner/work/hubflo/hubflo/test/controllers/companies_controller_test.rb:110]:
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>

rails test test/controllers/companies_controller_test.rb:104
```

I had to run this command before running the tests `bundle exec rake searchkick:reindex:all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<500: Internal Server Error>` indicates that some exception has been raised in your controller that wasn't properly rescued. If you can't reproduce the issue on your development environment you can:

1. Either add a `begin..rescue` in your controller's action, then inside the rescue do: `p $ERROR_INFO.message` ( `$ERROR_INFO` is a special variable that contains the last exception rescued, it's a more readable way to use `$!`

```rb
def my_controller_action
  # ... (business logic)
rescue
 p $ERROR_INFO.message
end
```

you can also add a global `rescue_from` in you ApplicationController

```rb
class ApplicationController
  rescue_from Exception, with: :my_exception_handler

private
  def my_exception_handler
    # exception handling logic ( logging to Sentry for example etc.)
  end
end
```

and here is a more detailed example [from the rails documentation](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from)

2. Or, with rails minitest, you can run `rails test --backtrace` (source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bb4a8a91884f3eff2b22d4deb3727d3cc267ddc4/railties/lib/minitest/rails_plugin.rb#L31)), there are more interesting options in there that you might want to use in your CI, or even when developing locally.